# iOS Google Maps SDK Not showing user location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm working on an app that uses google maps to display a set of pins, and I want the map's camera to start on the user's location. I tried writing the following code (in Swift 2.0) but it doesn't put me in the device's current location, instead it shows me a blank blue screen (which I have found to be the exact middle of the map). Here's a screenshot of what I have

[image: Here's a screenshot of what I have]

I used the following libraries while writing this code:

Google Maps SDK

OneShotLocationManager

Here's the code that I have (in ViewController.swift)

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var manager: OneShotLocationManager?

    var userlat: Double = 0.0
    var userlng: Double = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        manager = OneShotLocationManager()
        manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in

            // fetch location or an error
            if let loc = location {
                print(loc)
                self.userlat = loc.coordinate.latitude
            } else if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            self.manager = nil
        }


        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userlat,
            longitude: userlng, zoom: 6)

        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
        let infoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! CustomInfoWindow
        infoWindow.label.text = "\(marker.position.latitude) \(marker.position.longitude)"
        return infoWindow
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And here's the console output after running the app. Note that it does output the user's current location:

<+51.50998000,-0.13370000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2/3/16, 8:47:57 AM Pacific Standard Time
2016-02-03 08:47:57.545 Hanky Ranky[3379:260848] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.11.21919.0

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing two properties in ViewController.swift.

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var didFindMyLocation = false
```

The *locationManager* property will be used to ask for the user’s permission to keep track of his/her location, and then based on the authorization status to either display his/her current location or not. The *didFindMyLocation* flag will be used so we know whether the user’s current position was spotted on the map or not, and eventually to avoid unnecessary location updates.

This [Swift Tutorial for Google Maps](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate
{


    var placeName: String = "Default"
    var userlat: CLLocationDegrees = 0
    var userlng: CLLocationDegrees = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    acController.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userlat,
        longitude: userlng, zoom: 6)

    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.delegate = self


    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

    self.view = mapView

   }


  func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace!) {

    lat = place.coordinate.latitude
    longi = place.coordinate.longitude
    placeName = place.name
   }

}
```

I hope this helps...